# PHP openssl AES-256-ECB with IV

Tags: php, aes, php-openssl

I'm trying to connect to a PHP web service which is encrypted using AES-256-ECB with IV. I have been supplied with a key and IV.

I'm trying to decrypt a response starts:
W4Nhk94QkBHkCXcsQarx/do4bRaBbZepDNfVcT7bGkkmsCc+UgAZdIWZJegzB2lkwMRPQTynL

```
$iv='XXXXXXX';
$key='XXXXXXXX';

$response = $client->getQuote($params);
        $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($response, 'aes-256-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        echo $decrypted;
```

I get the following error:

Warning: openssl_decrypt(): IV passed is 32 bytes long which is longer than the 0 expected by selected cipher, truncating

Comment: The ECB mode doesn't use an IV. When applying a mode with IV, its size must be 16 bytes for AES (in general, the size of the IV corresponds to the blocksize of the cipher). The ciphertext seems to be Base64 encoded, i.e. it must either be Base64 decoded before decryption or the parameter `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` must be omitted. ECB is an insecure mode, better is CBC (confidentiality), even better GCM (confidentiality, integrity). And for the sake of completeness, AES-256 uses a 32 bytes key.

Comment: Many Thanks. I didn't think ECB supported an IV. The developer of the webservice said they are using an IV. I have asked them clarify.

Comment: if the response is base64 this is the correct code?  $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($response, 'aes-256-ecb', $key,0);

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, the 4th parameter can be omitted, as `0` is its default value, [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php).